# Expected payments through a contracts life using MS access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

- contract_ID
- Contract_start_date
- Contract_Duration
- Contract_amount
- Fixed_premium
- Pay_every_month

Sample Data:

- contract_ID: 5
- Contract_start_date: 01/01/2014
- Contract_Duration: 3 years
- Contract_amount: $90.000
- Fixed_premium: $15000
- Pay_every_month: 6 months

There should be an access query that uses the `contracts` data to generate a payments schedule as follows:

```
Contract ID......Due Date...............Amount Due
5                01 / 01 / 2014         $15.000
5                01 / 07 / 2014         $15.000
5                01 / 01 / 2015         $15.000
5                01 / 07 / 2015         $15.000
5                01 / 01 / 2016         $15.000
5                01 / 07 / 2016         $15.000
```

I used this SQL statement and it's not working:

```
SELECT
  Contracts.contract_ID,
  DateAdd("m",[Pay_every_month],[Contracts]![Contract_start_date]) AS Due_Date,
  Contracts.Fixed_premium AS Amount_due
FROM Contracts;
```

Access database file is [HERE](http://snk.to/f-c7tmatcd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal with Access SQL using a "numbers table". Create a table named [NumbersFromZero] containing integer values starting from zero and going as high as necessary to cover the largest number of payments for any contract, e.g.,

```
 n
--
 0
 1
 2
 3
...
98
99
```

Once that is in place, if we have test data like this in [Contracts]

```
contract_ID  Contract_start_date  Contract_Duration  Contract_amount  Fixed_premium  Pay_every_month
-----------  -------------------  -----------------  ---------------  -------------  ---------------
          5  2014-01-01                           3            90000          15000                6
```

then the following query

```sql
SELECT
    Contracts.contract_ID,
    DateAdd("m", NumbersFromZero.n * Contracts.Pay_every_month, Contracts.Contract_start_date) AS Due_date,
    Contracts.Fixed_premium AS Amount_due
FROM Contracts, NumbersFromZero
WHERE NumbersFromZero.n < (Contracts.Contract_Duration * 12 / Contracts.Pay_every_month)
```

will return

```
contract_ID  Due_date    Amount_due
-----------  ----------  ----------
          5  2014-01-01       15000
          5  2014-07-01       15000
          5  2015-01-01       15000
          5  2015-07-01       15000
          5  2016-01-01       15000
          5  2016-07-01       15000
```

Comment: Mr. Gord Thompson, Thank you very much this is what I have been looking for.